# BinaryTree inOrder Traversal Sorting complexity

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree

I am confused to why quicksort, shellsort, mergesort...all O(nlog(n)) algorithms repeatedly mentioned as popular sorting algorithms, Doesn't inorder traversal of a binarysearch tree give O(n) complexity to sort a tree? What am I missing?

Comment: No. Inorder traversal gives O(n) complexity for traversing a tree. It tool O(n log n) time to build the tree in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

No. Building the tree has O(N log N) complexity (i.e., you're inserting N items into the tree, and each insertion has logarithmic complexity).

Once you have the tree built, you can traverse it with linear complexity (especially if it's a threaded tree), but that's not equivalent to sorting--it's equivalent to traversing an array after you've sorted it.

Although they have the same asymptotic complexity, building a tree will usually be slower by a substantial factor, because you have to allocate nodes for the tree and traverse non-contiguously allocated nodes to walk the tree.

Comment: So What you are saying it takes O(nlogn) to insert all nodes to the tree, then inorder traversal would take also O(n) to get a sorted array. But assuming we already have a binarytree ready, sorting would be o(n), correct?

Comment: @sam2015: Assuming we already had a (sorted) binary tree, then sorting would be already done, but we could copy the sorted data from the binary tree to a sorted array in O(n).

Comment: Sorry for being a newbie, so binary tree is sorted by default? I thought you have to traverse in any way and inorder would sort it, while postoder for example doesn't?

Comment: @sam2015: Not all binary trees are sorted, but trees that support traversal in sorted order are basically sorted--yes, it's also possible to traverse them in other orders, but you basically do the work of sorting as you build the tree.

Answer (score 0):

Basically there are 6 types of complexity.
O(1),O(logn),O(n),O(nlogn),O(n^2),O(n^3).

For first part of your question why popular sorting algorithm are having O(nlogn) complexity its simply because we cannot sort an array in O(n) complexity.
Its because for O(n) complexity you want to sort the array in only one loop.
That is not possible since we cannot sort an array in one strech.

So the next possible complexity is O(nlogn). That is dividing and conquer method for example in merge sort 
We find the middle element sort each side  of that recursively. for recursion since it decreasing size to half each time the complexity is o(logn). For sorting part it make the complexity to O(nlogn).

For Next part of your question remember the fact that all basic operation like insertion,deletion in a BST is having the complexity of O(logn) where logn is the height of the tree.

So if you sort a tree using o(n) complexity that make it O(nlogn) in total.

Comment me if you didnt got  my point. This is the simple way to answer it i think.

Comment: What about O(n!) and O(2^n), etc. And those are just runtime complexity. There's also space complexity to think about. You really need to read up on complexity classes. Start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory

Comment: thanks for your concern. but i know about the space complexity and O(n!) complexity. i didn't know that sorting algorithm has O(n!) complexity.

Comment: And yet you said that there are "6 types of complexity," and didn't include them or others. The first sentence in your answer is incorrect and misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Any traversals of a binary tree is O(n). But that is not sorting.
Having a BST meaning that is already a sorted tree. You are just traversing it. Building a BST is the sorting process which is asymptotically O(nlog(n)).
Please note O(n) + O(nlog(n)) is same as O(nlog(n)).